# How to create new Javascript objects dynamically at runtime given their class names only?

Tags: javascript, oop, reflection

Let us say there are some widgets:

```
function Widget1(initData) {
        ....
} 
Widget1.prototype.render = function() {
    ....
}


function Widget2(initData) {
    ....
}  
Widget2.prototype.render = function() {
    ....
}
```

What I need to do is the following:

```
$.subscribe('/launch', function(widgetName, initData) {
    // create a new object of the widget and then call the render method
});
```

I dont want to write multiple if-else blocks as the number of widgets may become very large. One option is to use eval(), but I believe that there may be better techniques. I am using JQuery framework, so don't want to include any other frameworks that may have a specific feature to support this. A pure Javascript solution will be appreciated.

Comment: `eval('var x = new ' + widgetName);` would be one extremely ugly hackish massively bad way of going about it.

Comment: If they are globals you can do `new window[widgetName]()`

Comment: Why do they need to have their own variable definition? If they're just copies of some kind of Widget why not just add them to an Array indexed by whatever string makes sense.

Comment: Because each widget is complex, and each instance of the widget will have a separate state. While each instance will look similar to the other, it will render a different set of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, there is a way. When you create a function, it's created as a property of the `this` object in that context. So if you declare those Widget functions in the global scope, they become properties of the `window` object. As you probably know, you can access a property both as `object.property` or `object['property']`. So, if they are global, you can do something like:

```
$.subscribe('/launch', function(widgetName, initData) {
    var widget = new window[widgetName](initData);
});
```

EDIT: As T.J. Crowder said, I was horribly wrong. What I said about the function being created as a property of `this` applies when you're on the global scope (I want to say "only when you're on the global scope", but since I'm not 100% sure I'm gonna leave it as that).

Comment: *"When you create a function, it's created as a property of the this object in that context"* No, it isn't. That's only true at global scope. Within a function, it's not true at all.

Comment: I added a comment. And really: Ugh, I can't believe what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment from Esalijia said:

```
$.subscribe('/launch', function(widgetName, initData) {
    // create a new object of the widget and then call the render method
    widget = new window[widgetName]();
});
```

Or you can `bind` the scope of where `Widget*` is defined using `.bind()` and have them available to the `$.subscribe` method.